# Insert empty row after group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains transaction data. The rows with the same 'group_id' are a part of the same transaction. I am running the following SQL query to show all the transactions:
SELECT * FROM transactions

When I run this query I get as expected a list of all the transactions. But this large list makes it difficult to seperate the data with a different `group_id` from the other data.

For that reason I want to add an empty row at the end of the group_id, so I get:

`1
1
(empty row)
2
2
2`

instead of:

`1
1
2
2
2`

Can someone help me with this?

Here is my database:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9bf79/1

Comment: You want to format your data output but this is not what SQL is for. Where will your resultset be displayed? That is where to style your results. If you want to look at a particular `group_id` just add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

I do not suggest you do this at all but if you just want to separate two groups you could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE group_id = 1
UNION ALL
(SELECT '','','','','','')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE group_id = 2
```

Obviously this can added to if there are more group ids in the future but it is not a general purpose solution you are really better off dealing with appearance issues like this in application code.

Comment: Almost tempted to downvote... I think the answer should have been what others have commented, OP doesn't demonstrate understanding.

Answer (score 0):

you can use (abuse) rollup.

```
SELECT * 
FROM transactions 
group by group_id, id
with rollup
having group_id is not null
```

this will insert a row with `id` set to null after each group_id.

mysql will also sort by group_id because of the `group by`.

The group by id` makes sure that all rows are shown (your schema does not show it, but I assume id is unique? Otherwise you need to add other fields)

However only `id` will be null in the extra rows. The other columns repeat the value above.

You can filter them like this:

```
SELECT 
id,
case id is not null when true then date else null end as date,
case id is not null when true then group_id else null end as group_id
-- ....
FROM transactions 
group by group_id, id
with rollup
having group_id is not null
```

Alternatively:

```
 select * from
 (SELECT * 
 FROM transactions 
 union all
 select distinct null, null, group_id, null, null,null from transactions
 ) as t
 order by 3,1
```

but null values are sorted first, so the "gap" is in front of each section